# How to route RESTfully with multiple entry points?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, routes

I have a model called Project, which is a collection of information stored by a Company. This company can create projects two ways.

The first is the standard RESTful way - the company goes to the Project index, then clicks 'New Project', and upon creation is returned to the index with a flash message.

The second is a 'quick create' that can be accessed when a company is looking at a client's profile. From here, the company can enter some basic information and send this off to create a project with that client (the client is specified automatically here).

The second of these two scenarios has a project being accessed from clients/show. Sending this data to projects/create would ordinarily route the company to projects/index, but I don't want that. In this case, the create action is meaningfully different in that certain fields are treated differently, and the redirect is also different. What would you suggest I do?

1. Build an alternative 'create_from_client' action in projects.
2. Build a 'create_project' action in clients.
3. Send a parameter to projects/create and set client_id and redirect to client/show if that parameter exists.
4. Something else I'm not aware of.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just add another action to the controller, 'quick_create' or whatever. You can dry out the form with partials and parameters to the partial to tell how to render things...This just seems like the easiest way.

I've got this semi-rational (or is that semi-irrational) hang up against leveraging the referrer...

Comment: I'm curious to know what the reasons are - why a hangup against leveraging the referrer?

Comment: It's trivial to fake out and some browsers handle it differently. IE for example doesn't provide a valid referrer in certain cases. These issues are more than likely ironed out by this time but after years of avoiding the referrer it's hard to change my habits...

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage the referrer directly from the `Request` object and fork based on that, similar to how `redirect_to :back` works.

From the Rails API docs for the `redirect_to` options hash:

> :back - Back to the page that issued the request. 
>   Useful for forms that are triggered from multiple places. 
>   Short-hand for redirect_to(request.env["HTTP_REFERER"])

So you can simply do something like this:

```
def create
  @project = Project.new( params[:project] )
  @project.save
  respond_with @project, location: get_location!
end

private

def get_location!
  case request.env["HTTP_REFERER"]
  # Your routing logic here.
end
```

This is nice and easy to unit test, too, if you're into that. :)

```
context "if the user came from the regular form" do
  before { controller.request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] = "regular_form_url" }

  it "redirects to the index path" do
    post :create
    response.should redirect_to :index
  end
end

context "if the user came from the quick-create form" do
  before { controller.request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] = "quick_create_url" }

  it "redirects to some other path" do
    post :create
    response.should redirect_to some_other_path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I ussualy add hidden `referer` field with current URL then redirect to it

For example

```
def create
  @project = Project.new params[:project]
  @project.save
  respond_with @project, :location => params[:referer] || [:index, :projects]
end
```